# If else statement and selection of certain data only

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum

To describe my problem in easy way is, for example, I have frequency from `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `data = [4,7,2,1,4,9]` for each of the frequency. I need to make summation only data with frequency from 3-5Hz in MATLAB. How do I want to write code to satisfy my problem? Below is my trial to do the program code but not working.

```
f=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
data = [4,7,2,1,4,9];

if 3<=f<=5
    sumdata=sum(data);
else
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
f=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
data = [4,7,2,1,4,9];
validData = data(f <= 5 & f >= 3);
result = sum(validData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
f=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
data = [4,7,2,1,4,9];

sumdata = sum(data(3 <= f & f <= 5));
```

The operation: `3 <= f & f <= 5` give you a logical matrix of the value that met the conditions.

```
>> 3 <= f & f <= 5    
ans =    
     0     0     1     1     1     0
```

You can then use this logical matrix to get only the value corresponding to valid index in you data : `data(3 <= f & f <= 5)` and then, sum them : `sum(data(3 <= f & f <= 5))`.